# one-liner-return with 3 if-statements

Tags: python

I have the following Code in Python:

```
def show_sequence(n):
    if n > 0:
        return "+".join((str(i) for i in range(n+1))) + " = %d" %(sum(range(n+1)))
    elif n == 0:
        return "0=0"
    else:
        return str(n) + "<0"
```

Question: Is there a syntax correct way of putting all lines into one return statement if there are 3 if-statements?
I know it works with one if- & else-statement but im a fan of one-liner and already asked this myself several times.

Comment: Only if you wanted one absurdly long and hard to read line instead of code that makes sense.

Comment: I know, this is a bad example for clear coding but I could not figure out, how the syntax should look like. Already tried by using "or" but it did not work

Comment: `return "+".join(...) if n > 0 else "0=0" if n == 0 else str(n) + "<0"`. (But if anyone else has to read your code, please don't inflict this kind of syntax abuse on them).

Comment: https://rpo.library.utoronto.ca/poems/there-was-young-bard-japan

Comment: I wouldn't put everything on one line, but you also can easily generalize `n > 0` and `n == 0` into a single `n >= 0` case, as `"+".join([0]) == "0"` and `sum([0]) == 0`.

Comment: There's little more work involved in folding `n < 0` in there. `range(min(0,n),n+1)` will generate `[-n]` when `n` is negative, and `sum(range(-3)) == 0`, as the range is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Inline `if`-statements can be chained like this:

```py
"a" if 0 else "b" if 0 else "c"
```

(replace the `0`s with `1`s to see the return value change)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
result = True if a==b else False
```